# Проблема в заполнении таблицы mysql

Tags: python, mysql

Написал запрос для добавления позиции в таблицу базы данных, но получаю ошибку:

```
not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Вот мой код:

```
def save_action(id, save):

    values = (id, save)

    try:
        connection = pymysql.connect(
            host="localhost",
            port=3306,
            user="root",
            password="soldan1512",
            database="kvest_base",
            cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
        )
        print("successfully connected...")
        print("#" * 20)


        try:

        # create table
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            create_table_query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `save_action`(id int AUTO_INCREMENT," \
                                 " action varchar(32)," \
                                 " PRIMARY KEY (id));"
            cursor.execute(create_table_query)
            print("Table created successfully")

        # insert data
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                insert_query = "INSERT INTO `save_action` (id, action) VALUES (?, ?);"
                cursor.execute(insert_query, values)
                connection.commit()

        finally:
            connection.close()

    except Exception as ex:
        print("Connection refused...")
        print(ex)


save_action(1, '2')
```

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `?` на `%s` https://stackoverflow.com/a/49115701/7485582

Comment: @КириллМалышев спасибо помогло